# How to rotate an image with 45 degrees by using reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to incrementally rotate an image by 45 degrees one time, when the button was clicked, by using reactJs. But I have no clue how to do that. Can anyone give me some tips?

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with? Do you know how to handle click events?

Comment: Yes, I know how to handle click event. But I don't know how to rotate an image with 45 degree one click at a time.

Comment: I need a short example for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can keep the current rotation in the state of your component. And add an `onClick` handler which increments this by 45 at the time. Then use this variable in your `render`. Here is a quick codepen of how it could be implemented: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZrrWM

Comment: Useful. I'd recommend resetting the degrees once you reach 360 however. Rotated a bunch of times, inspected the element and saw: `transform: rotate(1035deg);`

Answer (score 3):

Just use CSS animations with `transform: rotate(45deg);`

Add that rule to a new CSS class, then use an event listener in JavaScript on the button that adds the transform to the image.

Comment: But how to add a function to rotate the image with 45 degrees, when user click the button at one time

Comment: Btw, can you give me an example

Comment: You need to add an event listener in javascript to the button - which when is clicked, adds a class to the image which contains the transform