# Rotate an image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rotation

I need to rotate an image by 90 degrees in React.
Here is my code:

```
rotatePic(id) {
  var newRotation = this.state.rotation + 90;
  if(newRotation >= 360){
    newRotation =- 360;
  }
  this.setState({
    rotation: newRotation,
  });
}

render() {
  const { rotation } =  this.state;
  const rot = {
    transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)`
  };
  return (
    <div className="gallery-root">
      {this.state.images.map(dto => {
        return <Image 
                 key={'image-' + dto.id} 
                 dto={dto} 
                 galleryWidth={this.state.galleryWidth} 
                 style={{rot}} 
                 width={this.state.width} 
                 height={this.state.height} 
                 imagesArr={this.removePic} 
                 imagesArr2={this.rotatePic}
               />;
      })}
  );
}
```

This doesn't work. Does someone know what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Would be nice if you show the `Image` code.

Comment: Try checking this answer i guess it will help
click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819091/how-to-rotate-an-image-with-45-degrees-by-using-reactjs)

Comment: Actually I used this in order to write my code but it didn't work well.

Comment: One thing to note--all your images will render with the same rotation. Is that the desired result?

Comment: Not really. I have a rotation button on each image and I'd like to rotate only the image whose button was pressed.

Comment: @Daniel In the code above, `this.state.rotation` is a single value, which is applied to all your images mapped in that code. Every time it changes, that component will re-render, and all the images mapped there will take on the new rotation. If each image is supposed to rotate individually, I would add the rotation code into the `<Image/>` component to let each image manage it's own rotation

Comment: @Ted That's what I was trying to do, unsuccessfully. The Image tag that is returned in the render function is a react object.

Comment: If you could copy your code into a [https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/) project, I could probably help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Change `style={{rot}}` to `style={rot}`.

The `style` prop expects a style object, your code nests the style object within another object.

Also, your code is missing the closing tag for `<div className="gallery-root">`

Comment: Yes it was missing here but I have it in my code. And I tried to remove the curly brackets from "style" but it didn't helped.

Comment: @Daniel then I would check your `<Image/>` component to be sure it does something with the passed style object, and I would check to be sure your `rotate(${rotation}deg)` string is being rendered as you expect. It's entirely possible the `<Image/>` component ignores the style object

Comment: I think this is the problem. How should I use the passed style object to the Image object?

Comment: @Daniel in your image component, assuming it is rendering an html image, add the passed style to the element, like `<img style={this.props.style} ...`

Comment: It is rendering a react object called Image. It's a part of a bigger project which consists of 3 objects.